# Video Rewind button control in VLC media payer

Tags: android

Actually I am trying to play video in my app,it plays but in that all controls(play,pause,forward) are working but rewind button is not working. Can you please suggest if you have any idea regarding this.

```
 vlcButtonRewind.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

         /*   if (libvlc.isPlaying()) {
             if (trickPlayFwd=true ) {
                 trickPlaySpeedRev = 1;
                 trickPlaySpeedFwd = 1;
             }*/
            trickPlayFwd=false;
            if (trickPlaySpeedRev<32){
                trickPlaySpeedRev=(trickPlaySpeedRev*2);
                trickPlaySpeed=(trickPlaySpeedRev);
                trickPlayRev=true;}
            else{
                trickPlaySpeedRev = 1;
                trickPlayRev =false;}

            // trickPlayRewind(trickPlaySpeedRev);
            Rspeed= String.valueOf(trickPlaySpeedRev);
            trickPlayRewind(trickPlaySpeedRev);   Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "<< " + Rspeed + "X", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM| Gravity.RIGHT, 0,0);
            toast.show();
          libvlc.setRate(trickPlaySpeedRev);

            int i =vlcSeekbar.getProgress();
           libvlc.setFrameSkip(true);

            dorev=true;

        }
    });
```

Comment: Please add some snippet code here for get solution

Comment: I updated my question please check